# Need hint for bipartiteness proof

Tags: graphs, proof-techniques, sets, proof-assistants

I am given a graph $G = (V, E)$ with $N$ connected components and $G^\prime = (V^\prime, E^\prime)$, where for each $v \in V$ there is $v_1, v_2 \in V^\prime$ and for each $(u, v) \in E$ there is $(u_1, v_2), (u_2, v_1) \in E^\prime$.

I need to prove:

$$G^\prime \textrm{ has 2N connected components} \Leftrightarrow G \textrm{ is bipartite}$$

I don't know what technique or approach I need to use to prove this in either direction. I have a feeling I can use a direct proof for both directions. I have tried to come up with something but after an hour nothing has come up.

Comment: Do you mean $G$ has $2N$ connected component iff $G'$ is bipartite?

Comment: No, I mean $G^\prime$ has $2N$ connected components if and only if $G$ is bipartite. @PålGD

Comment: So, is the point maybe that if you have an _even_ cycle in $G$, then that becomes _two_ cycles in $G'$, but if you have an _odd_ cycle in $G$, then that becomes _one_ long cycle in $G'$?  You are familiar with bipartite iff no odd cycle?

Comment: Yeh, I did notice that when playing with examples. But how do I formalize that idea? @PålGD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do the case $N = 1$.

Suppose that $G$ is a connected graph, and assume first that $G$ is bipartite, with bipartition $X,Y$. Let $X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2$ be the two copies of the two parts in $G'$. Note first that the edges in $G'$ either connect $X_1$ to $Y_2$ or $X_2$ to $Y_1$, and so $G'$ has at least two connected components.

Conversely, any path from $X$ to $Y$ in $G$ gives rise to a similar path in $G'$ from $X_1$ to $Y_2$, implying (after a short argument) that $X_1 \cup Y_2$ form a connected component; and similarly for $X_2 \cup Y_1$. Thus $G'$ has exactly two connected components.

Now suppose that $G$ is a connected non-bipartite graph. As before, the vertices in $X_1 \cup Y_2$ are all in the same connected component of $G'$, as are the vertices in $X_2 \cup Y_1$. We will show that $X_1$ is connected by a path to $X_2$, implying that $G'$ is connected.

Since $G$ is not bipartite, there is some odd cycle in $G$. Let $x$ be a vertex on this odd cycle. Lifting this cycle to $G'$, we obtain a path from $x_1$ to $x_2$.